# F# Tree Puzzle - Value or constructor "TreeNode" is not found

Tags: f#, compiler-errors, tree, discriminated-union

This is a beginner question, as I'm still figuring out what the F# compiler errors mean and how to fix them.

I have the following F# code - and can't see why it will not work. It is based off the solution found here: [F#: Recursive collect and filter over N-ary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815236/f-recursive-collect-and-filter-over-n-ary-tree)

```
module TreeProblem_Solution1 =

    type TreeNode =
        | N of int * TreeNode list

    let rec filterTree (t : TreeNode) (predicate : int -> bool) =
       ()

    let test =
        TreeNode(1,[TreeNode(2,[])])
```

The error i get is under ***TreeNode***(1,[TreeNode(2,[])]). I don't understand why this is causing a problem, when the nested TreeNode usage correctly displays the type and doesn't have any constructor problems, and I can also use this type as a method parameter.

Hopefully someone out there can shed some light on this, as I'm missing some vital insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this is not working is that `TreeNode` is a type, not a constructor. You have defined a type `TreeNode` with a single union case called `N`. In order to create a value of a Discriminated Union, you must use the name of one of it's union cases. In this example, there is only one to use - `N`:

```
let test = N(1, [N(2, [])])
```

More info on unions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx).

Comment: values of a discriminated union may also be qualified by their type: `let test = TreeNode.N(1, [TreeNode.N(2, [])])`

Comment: Arg! So obvious! Thanks. It's like being back at the "This is a function, this is a class" phase of C#. :)